# removing html from js and then putting in separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, typescript

**update**

*`whats happening here is when I click a link popup opens and in that I see all this html....smile method is called when I click the link and we are appending html in that method so that we can see it when I open  the popup...right now I moved it to separate file something.component.html but when I click the link I am not able to see the popup...since we removed append method...can you update the code in mycodebase...I tried but not sure how to achieve it`*

- I am trying to learn angular js
- I got the basic functionality working.
- but in my typescript file I am appending html.
- is there any way I can remove the html content and put it in a seprate html file
- and how to include the html content back into my ts.
- in this part of code `template: "<div id=\"sportsTable\"></div>"`
- basically I am trying to remove the html from the append method `$("#sportsTable").append(
- providing my code below.

```or-tag-here
/**
 * Animalsrun.ts file
 */
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  EventEmitter,
  ViewChild,
  Input,
  Output
}
from "@angular/core";
import {
  bikeService
}
from "../../services/fish.service";
import {
  KendoGridComponent
}
from "../grid/grid.component";
import {
  height
}
from "../shared/progress/progress-circle";

declare let $: any;

let lightWire = null;

@Component({
  selector: "Animalsrun",
  template: "<div id=\"sportsTable\"></div>"
})

export class Animalsrun implements OnInit {



  @Input() public kendoCommandObj: any;
  @ViewChild(height) public progress: height;

  private futureAirings = [];
  private pastAirings = [];
  public fishService: bikeService;

  constructor(fishService1: bikeService) {
    this.fishService = fishService1;
  }

  private kendocommand = {
    edit: {
      createAt: "bottom"
    },
    group: false,
    reorder: true,
    disableFreeze: true,
    resize: true,
    sort: true,
    autoBind: true,
    filter: false,
    pager: {
      messages: {
        // display: "Showing {0} to {1} of {2} entries"
      }
    },
    model: {},
    columns: [],
    pagesize: 50,
    getComponentUrl: "tiger",
    searchFields: [],
    mandatoryFields: [],
    saveStatus: false
  };

  @Output() public applyAPTInfo: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter < any > ();
  @Output("scoresCount") public getBoyEvent = new EventEmitter < number > ();

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.scoresType = "Contract";
    let attributes = this.fishService.getSeesionStorageValue();
    if (attributes) {
      this.userId = attributes.user_attributes.SSO[0];
    }

    let navHeaderHeight = $(".navHeaderBox").outerHeight();
    $(".breadCrumbBox").css("top:" + navHeaderHeight + "px");

    this.kendocommand.model = {
      id: "scoresId",
      fields: {
        contextRow: {
          editable: false,
          filterable: true
        },
        scoresId: {
          editable: true,
          filterable: false,
          sortable: false
        },
        scoresName: {
          editable: false,
          nullable: true
        },
        scoresType: {
          editable: true,
          nullable: true
        },
        scoresData: {
          editable: false,
          nullable: true
        },
        notes: {
          editable: false,
          nullable: true
        },
        elfDocID: {

        },
        url: {
          editable: false,
          nullable: true
        },
        date: {
          editable: false,
          nullable: true
        },
        addedByName: {
          editable: false,
          nullable: true
        },
        userID: {
          editable: false,
          nullable: true
        },
        operationType: {
          editable: true,
          filterable: false,
          sortable: false
        }
      }
    };

  }

  @ViewChild(KendoGridComponent) public gridkendo: KendoGridComponent;



  public smile(ball, source: string): void {
    $("#sportsTable").append(`
        <div class="nail"><div class="record-arrow-left"></div><div class="nail-label">Delete Boy</div></div>
        <div id="AnimalsrunPopup" class="baby">
          <div id="popup-loading"></div>
          <div class="row shirtHeader"><div class="shirtHeaderTitleBox">  <h4 class="kPopUpTitle">VIEW AIRINGS</h4>    </div><div class="shirtHeaderActionsBox">    <a id="forcloseBtn" class="commonLink triggerKPopUpClick" (click)=close()>CLOSE</a></div>
          </div><div class="clearFloat"></div>
          <div class="" style="` + (source === "contract" ? "display:none" : "display:inherit") + `">
            <div  class="subTabsBox popupSubTab"  id="cat"><div class="row subTabsContainer listSliderContainer">  <div class="scroller scroller-left inactive">      <i class="hand hand-chevron-left"></i>  </div>  <div class="scroller scroller-right inactive">        <i class="hand hand-chevron-right"></i>  </div>  <div class="subTabwrapper listSliderWrapper">    <ul class="nav nav-tabs list sliderList" id="subTabNav">    <li class="active" data-tab="snake-tab"><a>snake</a></li>    <li data-tab="contract-tab"><a>contract</a></li>    </ul>  </div></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="manage-tiger-tabs-container">                          
            <div id="snake-tab" class="manage-tiger-tabs-content active"><div class="row">  <div class="compBoxGrid financeDocComp">      <div class="pull-left">        <div>            <label class="fileContainer marginBottom0Imp"><div class="dragDropIcon displayInlineBlock marginTop5px"></div><span class="waveUploadInfoText">Drop tiger here to upload (Maximum scores size: 5MB)</span><input type="file" id="fire" [class.disabled]="isContractLocked" (change)="changeListener($event)" />            </label>        </div>      </div>      <div class="pull-right">        <label class="commonLink cursorPointer lineHeightInputs" (click)="browseButtonAdd()" id="forAttachBoyBrowseBtn" >        ADD NEW        </label>      </div><div class="clearFloat"></div>
                </div><div class="addELFBoyForm"><div class="baby kendoWindow kPopupConfirmationBox">  <div class="row shirtGridCollection shirtContent lineHeightInputs">    <div class="kendoContent">Do you want to upload the selected scores to contract.</div>  </div><div class="clearFloat"></div>    <div class="row shirtFooter textAligncenterImp">    <button class="commonBtn" type="button" id ="waveBoyOk" (click)="uploadFile($event,scores.value)">OK</button>    <button class="clearBtn" type="button" id ="waveBoyCancel" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>  </div><div class="clearFloat"></div></div></div><div class="deletePhotoShop" id="divdeletePhotoShop"><div class="baby kendoWindow kPopupConfirmationBox">  <div class="row shirtGridCollection shirtContent lineHeightInputs">    <div class="kendoContent">Selected scores will be deleted from contract permanently.</div>  </div><div class="clearFloat"></div>    <div class="row shirtFooter textAligncenterImp">  <button class="commonBtn" type="button" id ="deleteBoyYes" (click)="recordDelete(ball)">Delete</button>  <button class="clearBtn" type="button" id ="deleteBoyNo" >Cancel</button>  </div><div class="clearFloat"></div></div></div><div class="sizePhotoShop" id="divsizePhotoShop"><div class="baby kendoWindow kPopupConfirmationBox">  <div class="row shirtGridCollection shirtContent lineHeightInputs">    <div class="kendoContent">The scores size exceeds the max limit of 5 MB</div>  </div><div class="clearFloat"></div>    <div class="row shirtFooter textAligncenterImp">    <button class="clearBtn" type="button" id ="sizeBoyYes" (click)="recordSize()">CANCEL</button>  </div><div class="clearFloat"></div></div></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 popUpKGrid pad0Imp"><div id="waveBoysGrid" class="` + (source === "contract" ? "contractPopupkGrid" : "snakePopupkGrid") + `"></div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="" style=\"+(source === \"contract\" ? \"display:none\" : \"display:inherit\")+\">
              <div id="contract-tab" class="manage-tiger-tabs-content"><div class="col-sm-12 popUpKGrid pad0Imp"> <div class="padTop10px" id="waveTitleGrid"></div></div></div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- container -->
          <div class="clearFloat"></div>
          <div id="contextMenuItems"><ul class= "kendu-custom-contextmenu" id="context-menuWindows">    <li id="delWin">Delete Windows</li></ul>
          </div>
        </div>`);
    let that = this;
    $("#cat .sliderList li").click(function() {
      let tab_id = $(this).attr("data-tab");
      $("#cat .sliderList li").removeClass("active");
      $(".manage-tiger-tabs-content").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("#" + tab_id).addClass("active");
    });
    $("#cat .hand-chevron-left").click(function() {
      $("#cat .sliderList li").eq(0).trigger("click");
      $("#cat .hand-chevron-left").addClass("inactive");
      $("#cat .hand-chevron-right").removeClass("inactive");
    });
    $("#cat .hand-chevron-right").click(function() {
      $("#cat .sliderList li").eq(1).trigger("click");
      $("#cat .hand-chevron-left").removeClass("inactive");
      $("#cat .hand-chevron-right").addClass("inactive");
    });
    $("#fire").unbind().change(function(e) {
      that.changeListener(e);
    });
    $("#fire2").unbind().change(function(e) {
      that.changeListener(e);
    });
    $("#forAttachBoyBrowseBtn").unbind().click(function(e) {
      that.browseButtonAdd();
    });
    $("#waveBoyCancel").unbind().click(function() {
      that.cancel();
    });
    $("#waveBoyOk").unbind().click(function(evt, dropValue) {
      that.uploadFile(evt, dropValue, ball);
    });
    $("#waveBoySave").unbind().click(function(evt, dropValue) {
      that.uploadFile(evt, dropValue, ball);
    });
    $("#forcloseBtn").unbind().click(function() {
      that.close();
    });
    $("#deleteBoyYes").unbind().click(function() {
      that.recordDelete(ball);
    });
    $("#sizeBoyYes").unbind().click(function() {
      that.recordSize();
    });
    that.ContractInfoPopUpWindow = $("#AnimalsrunPopup");
    this.fileName = ball.excelFileName;
    that._dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      pageSize: 10
    });
    that.options = {
      excel: {
        fileName: "",
        allPages: true
      },
      dataSource: that._dataSource,
      selectable: "row",
      sortable: true,
      reorderable: true,
      resizable: true,
      editable: false,
      contextMenuId: "context-menuWindows",
      autoBind: false,
      pageable: {
        messages: {
          display: "Showing {0} to {1} of {2} entries"
        }
      },
      model: this.kendocommand.model,
      columns: ball.columns,
      dataBound: function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {}, 5000);
        $(".triggerBoyScroll").trigger("click");
        if (e.sender.dataSource.view().length === 0) {
          let container = e.sender.wrapper.children(".k-grid-content");
          let scrollOffset = {
            left: 0,
            top: 0
          };
          container.scrollLeft(scrollOffset.left);
        }
        $("#waveBoysGrid .contextMenuRow").bind("click", function(e) {
          $(".nail").blur(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            lightWire = null;
          });
          $(".nail").click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            let lightWire = $(this).parent().parent();
            if (lightWire != null) {
              // let recordToDelete = lightWire;
              $(".deletePhotoShop").show();
              $(".nail").hide();
              $(scores).on("click", "#deleteBoyNo", function() {
                $(".deletePhotoShop").hide();
              });
            }
          });
          let record_x = e.pageX;
          let record_y = e.pageY - $(".navHeaderBox").height() - $(".breadCrumbBox").height() - 20;
          $(".nail").css({
            left: record_x,
            top: record_y
          });
          $(".nail").fadeIn(200);
          $(".nail").show();
          $(".nail").attr("tabindex", -1).focus();
        });
        $("#unlockNo").click(function() {
          $("#unLockWindow").data("kendoWindow").close();
        });
      }
    };

    if (ball.snake === "SCORES") {
      let that = this;
      this.futureAirings = [];
      this.pastAirings = [];
      this.fishService.getResponse(ball.url, "get", null)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.gridData = data.scoresDtos;
            that._dataSource.data(this.gridData);
          },
          err => {}
        );
    }

    that.window = $("#AnimalsrunPopup");
    that.window.kendoWindow({
      width: "60%",
      snake: false,
      visible: false,
      resizable: false,
      actions: [],
      draggable: false,
      modal: true,
      open: function() {
        $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        that.isVisible = true;
        $(".kPopUpTitle").text(ball.snake);
        that._grid = $("#waveBoysGrid").kendoGrid(that.options);
        that._grid2 = $("#waveTitleGrid").kendoGrid(that.options);
        that.setscroll("waveBoysGrid");
      },
      deactivate: function() {
        this.destroy();
      },
      close: function(e) {
        $("html, body").css("overflow", "");
      }
    });
    $("#AnimalsrunPopup").prev().find(".k-window-snake").text(ball.snake);
    that.window.data("kendoWindow").center();
    that.window.data("kendoWindow").open();
  }



}
```

Comment: first: this is not angular js but angular 4, and what you mean "remove the html content and put it in a seprate html file". Components have templates and templates can have components. I don't understand what you want to do and missing part what you tried to do?

Comment: @daremachine - basically I am trying to remove the html from the append method `$("#sportsTable").append(

Answer (score 1):

In the same directory as your component you need to define an `*.html` file with the same name as your `*ts` file. `Animalsrun.html`, for example. Then change `template` to `templateUrl` and give the path to your html file. If you created the component using `ng g c component_name` then this should have been done for you.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my_selector',
    templateUrl: './something.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./something.component.scss']
})
```

Then you can write your html in the `something.component.html` file and it will run.

Comment: thanks for your reply but how to add the HTML file in the append method $("#sportsTable").append(`

Comment: Why aren't you just adding it to the table directly? In the html file you can create two table elements, both using *ngIf, and choose the one you want conditionally. If you really need to append the html in the typescript file then you can create some constants file in your project and pull it into your file or you can just create a variable somewhere in the file out of your way and define the html there.

Comment: thanks for your reply...whats happening here is when I click a link popup opens and in that I see all this html....smile method is called when I click the link and we are appending html in that method so that we can see it when I open  the popup...right now I moved it to separate file something.component.html but when I click the link I am not able to see the popup...since we removed append method...can you update the code in mycodebase...I tried but not sure how to achieve it